# Using rails sync gem with Faye and Thin in production mode on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webserver, thin, faye

I'm trying to set up the 'sync' gem to enable real time updates in my rails app. This uses Faye as a real time push service and thin as the webserver.

I"m VERY new to this. So any advice is appreciated.

I have this working on my local server, but don't know how to get it working in production mode on heroku. This is my setup:

In my gemfile:

```
gem 'faye'
gem 'thin', require: false
gem 'sync'
```

In my root folder, I have a sync.ru file

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "sync"

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter 'thin'

Sync.load_config(
  File.expand_path("../config/sync.yml", __FILE__),
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"
)

run Sync.pubsub_app
```

In my config/sync.yml

```
# Faye
development:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  adapter_javascript_url: "http://localhost:9292/faye/faye.js" 
  auth_token: DEVELOPMENT_SECRET_TOKEN
  adapter: "Faye"
  async: true

production:
  server: "http://my_app_name.com/faye"
  adapter_javascript_url: "http://localhost:9292/faye/faye.js" 
  adapter: "Faye"
  auth_token: "1b7329869f09aa98499258dfe9c377cdd2c89c05b99069176445942575348da0"
  async: true
```

On my local server, I simply run:

```
rackup sync.ru -E production
```

This starts the thin web server and real time updates work in my app.

How can I get this working on Heroku?

I've tried adding the following to my procfile (no idea if this is the right thing to do)

```
web:  bundle exec thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV -R sync.ru start
```

When I try and load my app, my browser displays the following text:

```
Sure you're not looking for /faye ?
```

And my heroku log reads:

```
app[web.1]: Starting process with command 'bundle exec thin -p 57204 -e production -R sync.ru start'
app[web.1]: Listening on 0.0.0.0:57204
app[web.1]: Maximum connections set to 1024
app[web.1]: Thin web server (v.1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 'rackup sync.ru -E production'
heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to start
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 sec of launch
```

Answer (score 3):

I deploy two heroku apps.
One is thin server for Sync pub/sub system which is deployed with your Procfile:

```
# this Procfile contains only the following line.
web:  bundle exec thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV -R sync.ru start
```

And the other one is default web server deployed without Procfile.

Also, I set the `server` and `adapter_javascript_url` params to point to my thin server in sync.yml.

```
production:
  server: "http://xxx-sync.herokuapp.com/faye"
  adapter_javascript_url: "http://xxx-sync.herokuapp.com/faye/faye.js"
  adapter: "Faye"
  auth_token: <=% ENV["SYNC_AUTH_TOKEN"] %>
  async: true
```

This approach work with HTTP protocol for me.

The message "Sure you're not looking for /faye ?" shows that thin server works fine.

Comment: in server setting it'd be http or https ?

Answer (score 0):

Have struggled a bit to get it work on staging/production. Posting my answer in case if someone is not not on heroku but on private server like EC2/rackspace etc.

You need to start the server with below command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rackup sync.ru -E production
```