# Running faye on heroku using Rails 4 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, faye

I am trying to implement a chat feature in my rails app deployed on heroku . For this I have created two rails apps one my original app and the other to acts as faye server.
I have given the faye app url in my original app to create faye server object.

Following is what I have added in my original app:

**Ruby version:** 2.0.0

**gemfile**

```
gem 'thin'

gem 'faye'

gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
```

**Application.rb**

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://xxx.herokuapp.com/faye.js' %>
```

**Application.js**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
  var faye = new Faye.Client('http://xxx.herokuapp.com/faye');
  faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
});
```

**Message Helper**

```
def broadcast(channel, &block)
   message = {:channel => channel, :data => capture(&block)}
   uri = URI.parse("http://xxx.herokuapp.com/faye")
   Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
end
```

**Message Controller**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.create!(message_params)
  end

  private
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

**My View:**

**messages/create.js.erb**

```
<% broadcast "/messages/new" do %>
    $("#chat").append("<%= escape_javascript render(@message) %>");
<% end %>
$("#new_message")[0].reset();
```

**/messages/index.html.erb**

```
<ul id="chat">
   <%= render @messages %>
</ul>

<%= form_for Message.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :content %>
   <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

Follwing is what I added in my faye server app:

**faye.ru**

```
require 'faye'

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
app = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25)

run app
```

**Procfile**

```
web:  bundle exec thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV -R faye.ru start
```

I am getting a `500 internal sever` error whenever I try to send a message. The code is working fine on local. Also I am getting `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404` in chrome.   I tried enabling cors but that did not helped either.

**Note:** Below are some reference links which are not working for me

1. [Using rails sync gem with Faye and Thin in production mode on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823859/using-rails-sync-gem-with-faye-and-thin-in-production-mode-on-heroku)
2. https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/10/8/websockets-public-beta

   This is not working `heroku labs:enable websockets`

**I am new for `heroku` and `faye`.**

Comment: Is `messages/create.js` the actual filename? Looks like you got some erb there, which i think requires you name it `messages/create.js.erb`. Also, what's your Message model look like?

Comment: yes, I pasted wrong. Edited.

Comment: I have also deployed `openshift`, could anyone have any idea about `openshift` regarding same?